# PHP Regex with recursively filter string and append sub-string to array

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm basically trying to extract parts of a string AFTER a character "/" but using PHP PCRE (Regular Expressions) NOT PHP substr() function, I would like to test if the initial string has multiple "/" characters using a combination of PHP PCRE (Regular Expressions) and preg_match() or preg_match_all().

I am able to select for a SINGLE iteration using a regular expression.

```
<?php
  $rules = array(
    'dbl'     => "/(?'d'[^/]+)/(?'p'[^/]+)", // '.../a/a' DOUBLE ITERATION
    'single'     => "/(?'d'[\w\-]+)",// '.../a' SINGLE ITERATION
    'multiple'     => "" //MULTIPLE ITERATION
  );
  $string = "a/b/c/d/e";
  foreach ( $rules as $action => $rule ) {
    if ( preg_match_all( '~^'.$rule.'$~i', $string, $params ) ) {
      switch ($action) {
        case 'multiple':
          $arr = explode("/", $string);
          print_r($arr);
          //do something
        ...
      }
    }
  }


?>
```

I know this is because of my lack of sufficient knowledge of Regular Expressions, however, I need a dynamic Regex code to match the condition that the initial string has multiple "/" characters and then recursively store these substrings to an array.

Comment: Something like `if(preg_match('~^[^/]+(?:/[^/]+)+/?$~', $string)) { print_r(explode('/', $string)); }`? If you want to check for at least 2 `/`s, replace the last `+` with `{2,}`

Comment: I would approach this differently: I would first explode `$string` on `/` and then apply logic based on the number of elements in the results.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, Yes, thats exactly what i needed. Kindly post your answer so that i may accept it.

Comment: Hi @joanis, Please explain further.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure I understand the final result. @joanis idea is better, you do not actually need a regex here.

Comment: In pseudo code since I'm not sure of php syntax off hand: `$arr = explode("/", $string); if (size of $arr == 1) { do stuff for 0 slash } else if (size of $arr == 2) { do stuff for 1 slash } else if (size of $arr == 3) { do stuff for 2 slashes } else if (size of $arr > 3) { do stuff for multiple }`

Comment: You might be able to use `switch(size of $arr)` instead of the chain if `if else if...`, but the concept is the same: don't use a regex to count the slashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question, Using Wiktor Stribiżew's Regex Code:

```
<?php
  $rules = array(
    'dbl'     => "/(?'d'[^/]+)/(?'p'[^/]+)", // '.../a/a' DOUBLE ITERATION
    'single'     => "/(?'d'[\w\-]+)",// '.../a' SINGLE ITERATION
    'multiple'     => "/[^/]+(?:/[^/]+){2,}/?" //MULTIPLE ITERATION
  );
  $string = "a/b/c/d/e";
  foreach ( $rules as $action => $rule ) {
    if ( preg_match_all( '~^'.$rule.'$~i', $string, $params ) ) {
      switch ($action) {
        case 'multiple':
          $arr = explode("/", $string);
          print_r($arr);
          //do something
        ...
      }
    }
  }


?>
```

For others who reference this resource, kindly upvote Wiktor Stribiżew's answer once/ if he posts it.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this differently: I would first explode `$string` on `/` and then apply logic based on the number of elements in the results.

```
<?php
  $string = "a/b/c/d/e";
  $arr = explode("/", $string);
  if (count($arr) > 2) {
    print_r($arr);
    // do something knowing there were 2 or more slashes in $string
  }
?>
```

If you need different actions for 0, 1 or 2 slashes, add `elseif` blocks testing for fewer elements in `$arr` and put the corresponding actions there.

Comment: This works but the aim was using Regexes to handle this as stated in the question.

Comment: Now I am curious, what is your use case for absolutely needing to solve this with a regex?